# Unpack nested tar files in s3 in streaming fashion

Tags: python, amazon-s3, tar, tarfile

I've got a large tar file in s3 (10s of GBs). It contains a number of tar.gz files.

I can loop through the contents of the large file with something like

```
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    input = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)

    with tarfile.open(fileobj=input['Body'],mode='r|') as tar:
        print(tar) -- tarinfo
```

However I can't seem to open the file contents from the inner tar.gz file.

I want to be able to do this in a streaming manner rather than load the whole file into memory.

I've tried doing things like

```
tar.extract_file(tar.next)
```

But I'm not sure how this file like object is then readable.

--- EDIT

I've got slightly further with the help of @larsks.

```
 with tarfile.open(fileobj=input_tar_file['Body'],mode='r|') as tar:
        for item in tar:
            m = tar.extractfile(item)
            if m is not None:
                with tarfile.open(fileobj=m, mode='r|gz') as gz:
                    for data in gz:
                        d = gz.extractfile(data)
```

However if I call .read() on d. It is empty. If I traverse through d.raw.fileobj.read() there is data. But when I write that out it's the data from all the text files in the nested tar.gz rather than one by one.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `tar.extractfile` is a "file-like object", just like `input['Body']`. That means you can simply pass that to `tarfile.open`. Here's a simple example that prints the contents of a nested archive:

```
import tarfile


with open('outside.tar', 'rb') as fd:
    with tarfile.open(fileobj=fd, mode='r') as outside:
        for item in outside:
            with outside.extractfile(item) as inside:
                with tarfile.open(fileobj=inside, mode='r') as inside_tar:
                    for item in inside_tar:
                        data = inside_tar.extractfile(item)
                        print('content:', data.read())
```

Here the "outside" file is an actual file, rather than something
coming from an S3 bucket; but I'm opening it first so that we're still
passing in `fileobj` when opening the outside archive.

The code iterates through the contents of the outside archive (`for item in outside`), and for each of these items:

- Open the file using `outside.extractfile()`
- Pass that as the argument to the `fileobj` parameter of
  `tarfile.open`
- Extract each item inside the nested tarfile

Comment: Hi - thanks for the quick response. This nearly gets me there. If I try and read the item in at the end of that loop it seems to come through as empty. Is there a way I could extract the actual data? The structure is tar -> tar.gz -> text files

Comment: Ideally I guess what I would do is stream the unpacked tar.gz back to s3. Keeping memory footprint low.

Comment: I have updated the answer to demonstrate how to access the content of the nested files.

Comment: Thanks - doesn't quite work for me. Have updated the question. Wonder whether it's the streaming aspect of my code