# High memory usage Lambda function (AWS) using Python tarfile Lib

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, tarfile

I'm trying to execute a Lambda function to decompress a TAR file inside an S3 bucket containing the file itself.

The point is that the TAR File dimension (12GB) exceeds the maximum RAM that AWS Lambda allows (10GB).

Indeed, I run out of memory when executing the lambda function:

> Memory Size: 10240 MB Max Memory Used: 10240 MB

Is there a way to use the tarfile library and keep the memory level low?

Below my Lambda function code:

```py
import logging
import tarfile
from io import BytesIO
from boto3 import resource
from urllib import parse
import io
import boto3
import botocore
import tarfile
import math
from io import BytesIO

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  
  invocation_id = event['invocationId']
  invocation_schema_version = event['invocationSchemaVersion']
  results = []                                                                                                                                        
  task = event['tasks'][0]
  task_id = task['taskId']
  key = parse.unquote(task['s3Key'], encoding='utf-8')
  obj_version_id = task['s3VersionId']
  bucket = task['s3BucketArn'].split(':')[-1]
  
  input_tar_file = s3_client.get_object(Bucket = bucket, Key = key)
  
  with tarfile.open(fileobj=input_tar_file['Body'], mode='r|') as tar:
      for tar_resource in tar:
          if (tar_resource.isfile()):
              inner_file_bytes = tar.extractfile(tar_resource).read()
              s3_client.upload_fileobj(BytesIO(inner_file_bytes), Bucket = bucket, Key = tar_resource.name)
  
  return {
    "invocationSchemaVersion": invocation_schema_version,
    "treatMissingKeysAs" : "PermanentFailure",
    "invocationId" : invocation_id,
    "results": [
      {
        "taskId": task_id,
        "resultCode": "Succeeded",
        "resultString": "success"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Might be better to do this with a short-lifetime EC2 instance if you can live with the startup latency. Also you seem to be getting the entire object first, and then getting chunks via the range option.

Comment: The point is that I have to execute the exact same task simultaneously on TAR objects within the same S3 bucket, which is why I had thought of S3's batch operations relying on a Lambda Function. 

If you look closely at the code, I call the get_object directly by taking the range, then iterate by incrementing the range to be taken in the get_object.

Comment: Your first call is `s3_client.get_object(Bucket = bucket, Key = key)`. I guess you're relying on the fact that the object is large and you're not touching the `Body` so limited to no streaming of the content happens.

Comment: exactly, the first call allows me to get the entire body content length. This doesn't create any problem.
The "Real" get_object call happens inside the for cycle.

Comment: Be aware of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68301982/unpack-nested-tar-files-in-s3-in-streaming-fashion

Comment: Yes, I see your link and I changed the code. Is there a way to free up the memory while processing the TAR file?